# I have connected two notes using bootnode in ethereum private blockchain but mining is not started why?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, mining, private-network

I have generated the enode from Bootnode in Ethereum private network and i connected three individual nodes using that enode 
through Bootnode, and i have checked whether that nodes are connected or not with my current node using
the command "admin.peers". 
[Screeshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuQb4.png)

those three nodes are conected successfully

then i start the mining using the command miner.start()
Geth not started 
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXKHH.png)

As of my observations i am getting the line constantly,

Line => "Regenerated local transaction journal transactions=0 accounts=0" for every one hour as we can see in the above screenshot
But even single block is not created

Question : Why is mining not started, How to start mining? please give me some suggestions and guide me if i am wrong

I have created simple gensis.json file. Please find below

```
{
"config": {
    "chainId": 1015
},
"difficulty": "0x400",
"gasLimit": "0x8000000",
"alloc": {
    "ef2df6e0a312875ca7e35d8d3579cf66df558193": {
        "balance": "30000000000000000000000000000"
    }}}
```

Comment: Share your private blockchain genesis.json file.

Comment: I have added genesis.json file to my question